Outline not visible for inline elements
I have an anchor tag. I have given an outline to this anchor tag. But this outline is not visible unless the anchor tag has a display: flex.
Here in the below example, there are two anchor tags. The first one does not have a flex container, but the second one has. And you can see the outline for the first anchor tag is not visible, but the outline is visible for the second anchor tag.
Why is this so?


.link {
  outline: 2px solid #000;
}
.link.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff2121;
}
<a class="link" href="">
    <div class="content">
    <h4>This doesnot have a flex container</h4>
    </div>
</a>
<a class="link flex" href="">
    <div class="content">
    <h4>This has a flex container</h4>
    </div>
</a>




The outline will be invisible for many elements if its style is not defined. This is because the style defaults to none .So you can try setting display:'block'

@DhruvilMehta I can see that, its visible when you define a display flex or display block to the element. Do we have any docs for this somewhere?

@DhruvilMehta no, styles with not default to display: none. The actual issue here rather appears to be, that a by default is an inline element, but there are block-generating elements inside of it - so the link effectively doesn't get the "real" dimensions it should here. Making the link itself block fixes that.

I hate inline tags, they have limitations but no significant advantages. I always assign display: inline-block to inline tags. There are many alternatives to having tags line up next to each other:

CSS property display

inline-block
inline-table table-cell Tables Element
inline-flex Flexbox Layout
inline-grid Grid Layout



In addition to avoiding display: inline, I suggest that you not waste your time with float as well (unless you need to wrap text around <img>s). Details are commented in example.


:root {
  font: 2vmax/1.35 "Segoe UI"
}

.link {
  /**
   * display: inline 
   * Default for <a>, <span>, <code>, <img>, etc
   *   - inline tags will sit beside each other on the same line
   *   - width and height are determined by content (and padding) 
   *   - width and height assigned in CSS are ignored
   *   - as are borders and outlines as well
   */
  border: 4px solid #00f;
  outline: 4px dashed #00f;
  outline-offset: 3px;
  color: #00f;
}

.inline-block {
  /**
   * display: inline-block;
   * Default for <button>, <input>, <select>, <textarea>, etc
   *   - inline-block tags will sit beside each other on the same line
   *   - width and height are determined by content (and padding) 
   *   - width can be assigned by CSS
   *   - borders and outlines are not ignored
   */
  display: inline-block;
}

.flex {
  /**
   * display: flex
   * There are no tags that are flex by default
   *   - characteristics are the same as the block tags, see the
   *     next comment block
   */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  /**
   * display: block 
   * Default for <div>, <p>, <section>, <section>, etc
   *   - block tags will take all of the horizontal space of the
   *     line it occupies.
   *   - height is determined by content (and padding)
   *   - width will be that of it's parent unless explicitly assigned
   *     by CSS
   *   - borders and outlines are not ignored
   */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 4px solid #f00;
  outline: 4px dashed #f00;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}


/**
 * The rest of the styles are for demonstration purposes only */

.indent {
  display: block;
  text-indent: 2.5ch
}

.flex small {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 2.5ch;
}

.NW::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(-2.5, -2.5) translate(20%, 20%);
}

.SW::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(-2.5, 2.5) translate(20%, 20%);
}

.NE::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(2.5, 2.5) translate(20%, -20%);
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

code {
  padding: 1px 2px 0;
  font-family: Consolas;
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}
<a class="link" href="#">
  <div class="content">
    <small class="NW">That's where borders and outlines end up on <code>inline</code> tags - useless.</small>
    <p>This <code>&lt;a&gt;</code> is <code>inline</code> (default).</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="link inline-block" href="#">
  <div class="content">
    <small class="SW NE"> 
    <code>inline-block</code> has both non/functioning borders and outlines.</small>
    <small class="indent">That's interesting...</small>
    <p>This <code>&lt;a&gt;</code> is <code>inline-block</code>.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="link flex" href="#">
  <div class="content">
    <p>This <code>&lt;a&gt;</code> is <code>flex</code>.</p>
  </div>
  <small><code>flex</code> is a <code>block</code> tag that changes their children into either <code>inline</code> or <code>block</code> with <code>flex-direction: row/column</code> respectively.</small>
</a>




Add some padding to see it


.link {
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.link.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ff2121;
}
<a class="link" href="">
  <div class="content">
    <h4>This doesnot have a flex container</h4>
  </div>
</a>
<a class="link flex" href="">
  <div class="content">
    <h4>This has a flex container</h4>
  </div>
</a>



The result is quite strange but it's the logical result of using block elements inside inline element. It's described perfectly here: Is it wrong to change a block element to inline with CSS if it contains another block element?

It looks like it doesn't for work with Chrome, also there's some small boxes on Firefox and Chrome with the black borders of .link.

@zer00ne that's the purpose of the answer; to show those black boxes and I am redirecting to the explanation about why those boxes are created.

The outline isn’t showing on the first <a> tag because <a> tags are inline by default, meaning they only take up as much space as their content. When you put a larger block element, like a <div>, inside an inline <a>, the outline doesn’t wrap around it correctly. Setting display: flex on the <a> tag fixes this by making it behave like a block element, allowing the outline to cover the entire content.
